# Max/min values of standard data types

Tags: solidity, evm, data-types, integers, uint256

Where can I find the maximum and minimum values that various types can store? And an epsilon value for floats?

I'm looking for something like C's `limits.h`, but for Solidity / EVM.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Updated 2020**

[Solidity 0.6.8](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/releases/tag/v0.6.8) introduced `min` and `max` keywords that can now natively tell you the min and max of an expected type. From the release page:

> Implemented type(T).min and type(T).max for every integer type T that returns the smallest and largest value representable by the type.

You can try it out with the following code. Note that the `uint256` values can be swapped for any valid integer type:

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.8;

contract TestContract {
    uint256 public a;
    uint256 public b;
    
    function myTest() external {
        a = type(uint256).min;
        b = type(uint256).max;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 19):

I assume you mean the integer types, because those are really the only types in Solidity that have a maximum and a minimum.

Solidity does not support floating point types, and most likely will never because they are considered not to be precise enough. Ethereum contracts need to be 100% deterministic, and always run the same way on all hardware.

Solidity will in the future support fixed-point types, but it doesn't yet.

Firstly, `int` means `int256` and `uint` means `uint256`.
Once you know the amount of bits your integer has, you can easily calculate the minimum and maximum using bitwise arithmetic:

```
int256 constant INT256_MIN = int256(uint256(1) << 255);
int256 constant INT256_MAX = int256(~(uint256(1) << 255));
uint256 constant UINT256_MIN = 0;
uint256 constant UINT256_MAX = ~uint256(0);
```

All the bitwise shifting is done on unsigned ints to avoid any special behaviour on the sign bit.

Comment: Cheers! FYI, standard like [IEEE754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) would run deterministically on all hardware. Regardless, there is a virtual machine abstraction layer.

Comment: @TomHale Yeah, a standard is a standard ofcourse. Thing is, I've had problems with 64-bit float arithmetic being compiled to extended precision 80-bit float arithmetic without anyone noticing. After the calculations were done, the compiler converted the 80-bit float back to 64-bit float. This caused apparent differences on different hardware, which was kind of a disaster. Ofcourse it was the compiler's and the programmers' fault, not the hardware's or the standard's. I guess I'm a bit prejudiced against floats :-)

Comment: [Fixed point and rational numbers do exist!](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/27838/15903)