# What is the neatest way to get hold of max uint256 in assembly?

Tags: solidity, assembly, uint256

Since [Solidity v0.6.8](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/83450/24693), the neatest way to get hold of max uint256 in Solidity is this:

```
uint256 foo = type(uint256).max;
```

Is there something like that for [Yul](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.3/yul.html#evm-dialect)? I couldn't find anything in the docs.

I know about `not(0)` but I don't like it much.